# MongoDB can't find just created document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a code that processes a file with users line by line in a loop and for each iteration works next code. If a user is unique, MongoDB inserts it in the collection otherwise it's just update the info. Unique ID is email of the user. The problem is the file has also duplicates of the user inside it.

The file looks like:

1. John - john@gmail.com
2. New John name - john@gmail.com (duplicate but with changed name)
3. Mark - mark@gmail.com
4. ...rest

My code processes it in the way that it insert 1. John in the DB, but the problem is that mongo DB can't find just created user with email john@gmail.com and takes (2. New John name - john@gmail.com) as a unique user.

Note: await calls are inside async function, so they should work fine.

Here is the code for it :

```
try {
            let user = await User.findOne({ email: email }).exec();

            if (user) { // here mongoose should find 1. John which was created on before loop iteration but it retuns null
                let update = {
                    name: newName,
                    email: newEmail
                }

                let updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    user._id,
                    {$set: update},
                    {new: true}
                );

            } else {

                let newUser = new User({
                    name: name,
                    email: email
                });

                let saveUser = await newUser.save();
                res.send('Users uploaded successfully');
            } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.send('Server error');
        }
```

Comment: can you log user and see what it is giving you?

Comment: You don't show this part of the code, but you say `line by line in a loop and for each iteration`. The problem is, you can't use `await` inside `.forEach()` (but you can inside a `for` loop

Comment: Yes, I guess that the problem is in the .forEach, I will re-write the code and see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reps too low to add a comment so excuse me for using an answer. I'd guess that the problem is the kind of loop you've used, but I can't tell without seeing more code.

If you've done `array.forEach` you're going to have a bad time. You'll want to do `for(let i in array)` type loop for async stuff.

Alternatively you can compile all the ops you want to do by mapping your array then doing `upsertMany` on your collection.

Comment: @mark-potter You are right, I am using .forEach, didn't know about that. You are amazing.  I will re-write the code quickly and get back here. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Yes, the problem was definitely in .forEach, swiping to for loop worked it out. Thanks again.